Ethical Concerns of Uninformed Authorship: A Case Study on Student Recognition by Supervisors
Previously, I asked a question and greatly appreciated the responses. Today, I would like to present a more detailed scenario for consideration.
Let’s assume the following situation:
PhD Student A, under the supervision of Professor B, has some experience in thermal simulations. Professor B collaborates with a research group at another university to publish a paper on thermal sensors. After the paper is completed, the main authors revise the manuscript.
Since the sensor design requires thermal simulations to determine the optimal design parameters for subsequent sample production, Professors B and C (the corresponding author) recognize that Student A’s extensive experience in thermal simulations within Professor B’s research group could add significant value to the revisions. After discussions, they decide to list Student A as the tenth author.
However, Student A was not informed of this decision before the paper was submitted, was unaware of the paper’s existence, and had not directly participated in the project. A only became aware of their authorship upon receiving the submission notification. A tacitly accepted Professor B’s decision. It wasn’t until after the paper was accepted that Professor B first explained, 'This is a collaborative project with another university, closely related to your work.'
Is this considered inappropriate authorship? How severe is it? Should Student A bear any responsibility? Could this affect A’s degree, assuming the paper is unrelated to their dissertation and doctoral research?
If the above scenario is too complex, let's consider a simpler one: Two research groups, Group X and Group Y, collaborate on a project, but Student A from Group X did not participate in the project. If Student A meets the following criteria: (1) they work in Group X, (2) their research area is highly relevant to the collaborative project, and (3) the primary authors believe A should be included as an author, do these three conditions warrant substantive authorship (i.e., relative later authorship, such as being the tenth author)?

"recognize that Student A’s extensive experience in thermal simulations within Professor B’s research group could add significant value to the revisions" I don’t understand what this is supposed to mean. If B and C are interested in A's experience, then they would include that in the paper somehow, wouldn’t they? Based on that I would expect A's expertise to directly (via advice on the content of the paper) or indirectly (via work on simulation used in the paper) contribute to the paper. Was there absolutely none and just the name added to the paper?

@MisterMiyagi  I'm sorry, my previous wording might have been inaccurate. What I meant is that A was working on their thermal simulation project under the guidance of Professor B. While revising the paper, Professors B and C realized that the paper could be improved and refined based on A's work (A's simulation work is much more complex than the thermal simulation mentioned in the paper).

@MisterMiyagi  Essentially, A did not make any direct contributions, but Professor B believes that A's work is highly relevant to the content of the paper, and B considers this relevance sufficient to constitute a contribution. The other authors also agree with this.

Not in academia, so please take this with a grain of salt, but I feel like there is a step missing here. They realize student A can contribute. Surely then Student A needs to do some actual contributions to then be considered an author. What did Student A contribute? Was their work on other projects helping the professor on this project? Can that count as a contribution or would that have to be a citation?

@user_ababa_gwzddx There is quite a difference between "the paper could be improved and refined based on A's work" and "A's work is highly relevant to the content of the paper". The first means some of the student’s work was used in the paper, the second means nothing concretely. Please don’t focus on making the story more or less complex, focus on explicitly spelling out just how student A's work was used for the paper or not.

Is the idea here that student A’s prior discussions with B or presentations in B’s lab helped B to formulate the ideas in the paper? This is something that is sometimes argued in the other direction… as in the professor had lots of helpful conversations with the student on the topic of the paper (even if not directly on the paper contents) so should be an author. But that is not the bar for authorship in most fields.

To clarify my earlier confusion, "their research area is highly relevant to the collaborative project" doesn’t say anything about whether their expertise was actually used or not and how. For almost every paper I did contribute to my research area was highly relevant, and for lots of papers I did not contribute to my research area was highly relevant as well. Relevance is not an indicator for contribution either way.

@TheEvilMetal  Thank you very much for your response! Since A did not contribute to any part of the article or make any direct contributions, I believe the most appropriate course of action would be to cite A's previously published related work. If A has not published any related articles, then acknowledging A in the acknowledgments section might be more suitable.

@MisterMiyagi   Thank you very much for your response. As you pointed out, there is indeed a distinction between 'the paper is based on A’s work' and 'A’s work is highly relevant to the paper.' I understand your confusion and will clarify further.

@MisterMiyagi  Here is the situation: A is conducting work highly related to the content of the paper within Professor B’s research group. Professors B and C believe that A’s work provides valuable references for the improvement and refinement of the article. If Professors B and C had not collaborated and A had published relevant articles, Professor C would have directly cited A’s publications rather than including A as an author. However, since A is part of Professor B’s research group and B and C are collaborating, Professor C chose to list A as a co-author instead of simply citing A’s work.

@Dawn  You make a very valid point. Following your reasoning, let me further explore the following scenario: Suppose A frequently discusses their work in Professor B’s lab, and these discussions are closely related to the thermal simulation section of the collaborative paper. For example, they discuss variations in temperature distribution across different-sized geometric models under the same heat source and the extent of thermal deformation caused by high temperatures.

@Dawn  This detailed experiential knowledge might be highly valuable for Professor C’s research group, especially if their primary research focus seldom involves these specifics or if they lack expertise in simulation details. In such cases, would this kind of support in simulation experience warrant substantial authorship?

Maybe- if by “support” you mean you helped the main authors with their code in a critical way or discussed their problems with them such that they had a breakthrough. But in my field all authors must not only contribute in such a way, but also be sent the paper in advance, read it, and approve.

Based on the "clarification" comments on the question and some answers, I have to ask: Is this an actual situation that happened and you are just trying to generalise/anonymise, or is this an artificial scenario? Specifically, the comments on BryanKrause's answer shifting the timeline of when the student was expected to contribute their expertise seems to ever so slightly change the scenario.

@MisterMiyagi  Indeed, the scenario described is based on real cases and is drawn from the experiences of many students around me. It appears very authentic because it is based on genuine occurrences. These situations are not confined to a specific individual; therefore, I have used hypothetical scenarios to illustrate the points.

@MisterMiyagi  The scenario I have described is based on real occurrences. As a student, the concern is that papers published under the student's name may not reflect any actual contribution from them. The student is deeply worried about the possibility of being accused of academic misconduct in the future and is seeking advice on how to address this issue.

Probably too late now, but for future, please avoid writing questions with more than one variable. It's much easier to follow if the names are "my advisor" and "the prof at the other university" than "Prof Y from Univ A with Prof Z from Univ B...." If the question is hypothetical, you can always clarify that at the end (though we generally discourage hypothetical questions, since the answer is often "it depends").

@cag51  Thank you for your feedback. I used multiple variables in my question because the scenario was a composite of several real situations. As a result, I opted for variables like A and B rather than using terms like ‘my advisor.’ I understand that this approach can be confusing. Perhaps a better method would be to present the scenario directly from the perspective of ‘I,’ narrating it as if from my own viewpoint.

It is possible that your supervisor and professor C believe that your work contributed to their approach to the problem and the paper in a (less direct) way. Perhaps you made critical points when presenting your own work during a lab meeting or similar. In this case B might feel that your unpublished work and ideas changed their part of the paper.
In most fields, this would not be enough for authorship. At the very least, they should have given you a chance to review the manuscript as well. You should also have been told in advance.
However, it does happen that these sort of “advisory conversations” are sometimes claimed as a basis for authorship. Usually what happens is that a supervisor insists they should be an author due to giving general advice. The direction of your situation is more unusual.
I can tell you are very worried about this problem. In general, it is recognized that PhD students don’t have a lot of power in these situations and overall need to accept what their supervisors say regarding the conventions of authorship in their field. If ever asked, you can say that your supervisor informed you that you contributed ideas and should be an author, which you accepted because your advisor is more knowledgeable about professional norms of authorship in your field. It should not get you in trouble in terms of your degree because you have the support of the advisor, whose opinion is most critical to degree completion.
I agree that you should ask to be more involved in future work where you are named as an author, as Bryan says. You might suggest to the students in labs B and C to develop a process where the paper is sent to all authors for “final approval” before any submission in either lab. This may work because I doubt the professors are doing the administrative work and submitting their own papers. But the most important thing is that if you are ever a faculty member you should only include authors who make substantive contributions.

First, I greatly appreciate your response! In fact, the scenario described above is based on real events and reflects the experiences and situations of several of my peers. What is most frustrating is that students are deprived of their right to be informed.

By the time the issue arises, students often find themselves powerless to change the situation, as the paper has already been submitted, and any changes to authorship would imply a public conflict with their advisor. In other words, regardless of whether the student made a substantive contribution, they typically have no choice but to accept the situation.

If a student later finds out that they did indeed make some contribution, this may only involve the issue of being informed. However, if the student is certain that they had no involvement in any part of the paper, such an authorship without contribution is clearly a case of academic misconduct. At this point, the student would have to choose between contacting the editor to withdraw the paper—potentially offending their advisor—or accepting the fact that they are implicated in academic misconduct.

I understand the power dynamics. Maybe the thing to ask in the future is that at least all authors should be sent the paper and attend a meeting for giving approval before submission. At least that will be closer to correct practice and should not be a huge ask of the PI.

Your observation is accurate. The scenario described is not an isolated incident; such issues have been persistent within the academic community. From a student's perspective, the current concern is that papers published under the student's own name do not actually reflect any substantive contribution from the student. There is a significant worry about the potential for being accused of academic misconduct in the future, and guidance on how to address this issue is being sought.

Most of the academic misconduct is on the part of the supervisors, and it would be very costly to try to change the past with these fuzzy grey areas. I would suggest trying to change the future. I doubt that B or C are submitting their own papers. Have an agreement that all of B’s students will adopt the practice of sending the manuscript to all authors before submission. Then maybe say, we always do this, we request that C’s students also do the same as a matter of courtesy and respect for us. Don’t accuse C of anything, just ask their students to adopt a professional practice.

At least if you know you are being named as an author you have a chance to evaluate if you maybe contributed somewhat and try to wiggle out of it if not.

To facilitate the discussion, I will use "I" to refer to A. I have been listed as an author and, upon evaluating my contribution, I believe that while my simulation experience may have been useful, it does not merit authorship.  I am attempting to disassociate myself from this authorship. However, it is clear that directly withdrawing the paper or contacting the editor would likely offend many and jeopardize my research career. Contacting my supervisor would also be ineffective, as such issues with improper authorship should not occur if they were an ethical and principled researcher.

Yes, I understand and you don’t need to clarify. My advice of dealing with this somewhat for the next paper vs this paper stands.

Thank you very much for your advice. What's done is done, and we should focus on the future.

Initially, I had the impression from this part of OP's post:

Professors B and C (the corresponding author) recognize that Student A’s extensive experience in thermal simulations within Professor B’s research group could add significant value to the revisions.

that Professors B and C were abusing the peer review process by submitting an incomplete manuscript and hoping to get it through review, while having A proactively on the author list for expected revisions in their area of expertise. In that case, they should be adding A's contributions now, not after peer reviewers ask for it, if they think it's important enough to justify adding an author the paper.
From a lengthy comment discussion, it instead seems like B and A had discussions previously that B found pertinent to this paper and informed the direction of the paper, and that this is why A was added to the author list, not because A might contribute to future revisions.
The things that happened wrong here seem to be 1) that B and C added A to the author list without consulting them about it, and 2) that the manuscript was submitted without all coauthors approving, which is a pretty standard requirement from journals and expectation for authorship.
However, I wouldn't expect any of this bad behavior by B to have any negative impact on A. Even if the paper is poor quality (which isn't mentioned here), that would mostly just reduce its value to A rather than causing negative value. If the paper is worse than poor quality (e.g., fraudulent) that could be more of a problem, but it's probably not this particular paper that would be the issue but rather the overall culture of the research group that A is in.
In fields I am familiar with where work is collaborative and author lists as a result can be quite long, it is not unusual for Jth and Kth authors to have had relatively small contributions to the sum total. These fields use authorship to recognize the value that someone with distinct expertise can offer a project even if it only affects one figure panel that is necessary for the paper. That also means that being a Jth or Kth author doesn't represent to third parties that someone in A's situation is claiming to have had a central role in the project: they're 10th author, so what. In a collaborative environment, it may be expected that someone has several of these sorts of contributions for every "first author" work.
Rules against "gift authorship" (adding authors who have not actually contributed to a paper) are mostly targeted towards adding senior authors, who may use their clout to manipulate others to inflate their own publication count, or attempts by authors to add importance to their paper by including someone famous. For junior authors, it's much more common for contributions to be under-recognized. There is little abusive potential in adding a junior author to a publication. In some cases a well-meaning advisor might abuse the system to prop up a mentee who is having trouble with their own publications, but that's still something that is the fault of the advisor, not the student.
I would recommend A ask firmly that they be consulted before their name is added as an author to anything in the future but otherwise to focus on their own work and progress toward their degree. If they make it to more of a decision-making role as a PI in the future they can choose to behave better than their mentors have. I do not think it is feasible that anyone will go after A with any accusations of misconduct for any part of this, A hasn't done anything wrong.
I also don't think B is intending any malfeasance here, it seems more of an oversight and a bit of sloppiness while trying to do the right thing by crediting junior personnel who contributed to a project (whether or not they knew they were contributing at the time).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
